# Azure Key Vault Certificate Thumbprint Format Mismatch

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am attempting to retrieve an ssl certificate's thumbprint via Azure's REST API and convert it to a hex value from within a Logic App. The return value from the REST API includes a property `x5t` which contains the thumbprint:

```
{
  "id": "https://myvault.vault.azure.net/certificates/selfSignedCert01/f60f2a4f8ae442cfb41ca2090bd4b769",
  "kid": "https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/selfSignedCert01/f60f2a4f8ae442cfb41ca2090bd4b769",
  "sid": "https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/selfSignedCert01/f60f2a4f8ae442cfb41ca2090bd4b769",
  "x5t": "a9gQzwmHiKJ3vHoKhXVTFuMohMX",
...
```

However, what I need is the thumbprint in the format that shows up in the portal, which says it is in hex:

[image: Portal Screenshot]

In text format:

```
X.509 SHA-1 Thumbprint (in hex)
54795FFE62D9088DD6D4AA47393...
```

This hex value is what I subsequently need to write to a separate secret. (Azure, why do you represent the thumbprint in this apparently non-standard format? This is also the format used in certificate stores when searching for certificates, which is why I ultimately need it. But I digress...)

How can I convert from the `x5t` string value returned by the REST API, which I believe is base64 encoded binary(?), to the hex value used in the portal as a Logic App step? I'm not finding a "base64 text to hex" conversion function.

EDIT:
I can successfully use the `baseto64String()` function in a Compose step if I pad the value with '=' to a multiple of 4 characters. That gives me the binary representation like so:

```
Outputs:
k�� ���w�z
�uS�(��
```

Now I just need to figure out how to make that hex within the Logic App. Example in python that works:

```
import base64
base64.b64decode('a9gQzwmHiKJ3vHoKhXVTFuMohMX=').hex()
```

Comment: I can't see your screenshot (it's blocked on my network) - can you post the text? Have you tried urldecode?

Comment: Updated. I tried a number of the base64 functions, but then I'm not sure how to turn it into the hex representation (if it is indeed base64 encoded which is what RFC7517 says it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an Azure Function that can be called from the Logic App:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// This function takes a base64 encoded string and converts it to hex. This is useful for converting the x5t
    /// certificate thumbprint the key vault REST api returns to the hex thumbprint the .net API expects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logger"></param>
    /// <param name="base64value"</param>
    [FunctionName("Base64ToHex")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Base64ToHex(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request for Base64ToHex.");
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic bodyData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        var encodedString = bodyData?.encodedString;
        var responseMessage = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodedString))
        {
            responseMessage = /*lang=json,strict*/ "{\"error\":\"No encodedString provided\"}";
        }
        else
        {
            encodedString = encodedString.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
            encodedString = encodedString.PadRight(encodedString.Length + (encodedString.Length * 3 % 4), '=');
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
            responseMessage = $@"{{""hexString"":""{Convert.ToHexString(data)}""}}";
        }
        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
```